# jQuery menu without images and background-position animation plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

my example is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lechoo/qSvDz/73/). I'm not sure is this the best way for this. Is it better solution for this menu but without images and background-position animation plugin? Sorry for my english - thx, Lechoo.

Comment: Are you asking is there a better solution than what you have?  Better as in more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could better give all the menu items id's instead of classes since that isn't really necessary.
But for the rest it looks good.